# 2d numerical integration

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I'm trying to get a numerical solution for a double integral:

```
n=0.8; f=0.25; g=0.1; a=0.1;
q[v_, x_] := n Sinh[v/f]-2(v-g Tanh[x/a]) Cosh[v/f] ;
d[v_, x_] := (1/100)*(n Cosh[v/f]-2(v-g Tanh[x/a])Sinh[v/f]);
```

Now I integrate over `v` and also plot it for every value of `x`

```
Plot3D[(1/d[v, x])*Exp[NIntegrate[2 q[s, x]/d[s, x], {s, 0, v}] ], {v, -0.5, 0.5}, {x, -.1, .1}]
```

But I wish to integrate this all result, and get a graph as a function of `v`,something like:

```
Plot[NIntegrate[  1/d[v, u] Exp[NIntegrate[2 q[s, u]/d[s, u], {s, 0, v}]], u, 1, 1}], {v, -0.28, 0.28}]
```

But I'm missing the integration summation for `s` ,How does this suppose to be written in mathematica?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just supply two domains to `NIntegrate[]`?

Comment: @Feyre, I didn't manage to do it so far

Comment: But if you want to define a function, you can't use `NIntegrate[]` at all, `NIntegrate[]` works numerically after all.

Comment: @ Feyre, I've edited the last part and also tried it with Integrate cmd, I did not get a result

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematics issue. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: Your last line of code has syntax errors.  What's it suppose to be?  Why change x to u?  Does u run from -0.1 to 0.1?  (You can just edit the question instead of responding to the comment.)

Answer (score 3):

With your definitions, use:

```
integral[v_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
   (1/d[v, x])*Exp[NIntegrate[2 q[s, x]/d[s, x], {s, 0, v}]]

Plot3D[
   integral[v, x], {v, -0.5, 0.5}, {x, -0.1, 0.1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[Read this FAQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/27951) to see why you need to use `NumericQ` in this case.

Having said that, your function assumes insanely high values in some regions of your plotting domain. You may have to consider numerical instabilities, precision issues, domain restrictions, or perhaps a different way of presenting this data.

Comment: This is a progress, however, how do we integrate the result over the x coordinate here?

Answer (score 3):

The interior integral, done by [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).  We save the results for speed.

```
Clear[i1];
i1[u_?NumericQ] := 
 i1[u] = NDSolveValue[{ff'[s] == 2 q[s, u]/d[s, u], ff[0] == 0}, ff, {s, -0.28, 0.28}]
```

The outside integral `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0` is for speed, which it seems to give in this case, and the interval for `u` is assumed to be `±0.1`, as it was for `x` in the first `Plot[]` command in the OP:

```
f1[v_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[1/d[v, u] Exp[i1[u][v]], {u, -0.1, 0.1}, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[f1[v], {v, -0.28, 0.28}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternative:

```
f2[v_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[1/d[v, u] Exp[
    NIntegrate[2 q[s, u]/d[s, u], {s, 0, v}, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]],
  {u, -0.1, 0.1}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]


Plot[f2[v], {v, -0.28, 0.28}]
(* same plot as above *)
```

The function `f2` takes about a minute compared to a couple of seconds for plotting `f1`.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `f1`, not `f3`? Do you know why `NDSolve` is so much faster than `NIntegrate` in this case?

Comment: @sebhofer Yep, `f1`, thanks. As for speed, it's because `i1[u]` is computed only once for all `v` between `±0.28` and the values of its memoized `InterpolatingFunction` are used & reused (`i1[u][v]`) in the outside integral; whereas, the `NIntegrate` is recalculated for each `v`.  Even if the recursive subdivision of `{u, -0.1, 0.1}` is different for each `v`, a lot of values of `u` will be repeated because the `"GaussKronrodRule"` uses the same sampling points for a given subinterval.  (If it were a Monte Carlo type rule, then one would lose this advantage.)